# Почему python неправильно переводит типы переменных?

Tags: python, float, int

Столкнулся с проблемой: при переводе переменной из `float` в `int`, python переводит числа с дробью в меньшую сторону. Например: `1.6` переведет не как `2`, а как `1`, хотя из курса математики известно, что должно быть `2`. Объясните, почему это происходит и как с этим бороться?

Comment: Наверное так всем программистам привычней. Традиционные языки (Си, Фортран и т.п.) при присваивании целой переменной отбрасывают дробную часть, а не округляют. Бороться с этим не надо, надо просто принять такую логику.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вполне возможно это часть синтаксиса, в данной ситуации можно использовать round(), но может работать не точно и с ошибками.

Comment: Это не косяк синтаксиса, это всем известное ожидаемое поведение.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий уже поправил ответ

Answer (score 4):

Если хотите округлить

```
round(1.6, 0) = 2
```

int отбрасывает дробную часть

```
int(1.6) = 1
```

ceil возвращает ближайшее большее

```
math.ceil(1.6) = 2
```